# PPPoE and FreeRadius

Tags: radius, pppoe

We have a number of wireless clients using ubiquity radios that support PPPoE. 
The number of connected clients is currently sitting around 20.  But this is increasing rapidly and we want better control so we plan to authenticate users against a freeradius server using PPPoE.

Things we want to control are authentication, bandwidth management and accounting.

I was wondering if someone could recommend an appropriate howto on the subject.

Is there a web interface available that allows all this functionality to be controlled from the one place?  set up the firewall rules etc.

My preference is FreeBSD but might consider a linux solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a pretty good tutorial : http://www.freeantennas.com/PPPoE-Server-HOWTO.html

DialupAdmin ( http://freeradius.org/dialupadmin.html) is a freeradius web interface

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to delve into this HOWTO for Mikrotik, although it's a competing product the FreeRadius notes are pretty extensive:

http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/RouterOs_MySql_Freeradius

I would highly also recommend DailupAdmin as mentioned by @Dominik and then there is the book [Radius](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596003226) that could help you a lot.

Good luck with your journey!